# Predict a class from the results of a detected object of trained YOLOv8 model in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, yolov8

I have a trained model and I have detected my required object using following code

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from ultralytics import YOLO

image = cv2.imread("screenshot.png")
model = YOLO('runs/detect/train4/weights/best.pt')
results = model.predict(image, show=True, stream=True, classes=0, imgsz=512)
for result in results:
    for box in result.boxes:
        class_id = result.names[box.cls[0].item()]
        if (class_id == "myclassname"): 
            cords = box.xyxy[0].tolist()
            cords = [round(x) for x in cords]
            conf = round(box.conf[0].item(), 2)
            print("Object type:", class_id)
            print("Coordinates:", cords)
            print("Probability:", conf)
            print("---")
```

From this detected portion of image I need to detect an other class how I can do that?

I have searched enough but I could not see any post for this.

Comment: so... you're asking how to slice a region from an image?

Comment: Not slice I am willing to predict again from the detected portion (box, cordinates) of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the xyxy box coordinates ([x1 y1 x2 y2]), slice (crop) the box area from your original image: `box_image = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]`, and make another prediction on this cropped image with the changed 'classes' parameter to the relevant class id: `model.predict(box_image, classes=0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @hanna_liavoshka it worked I made following function that gets main image and box to return image

```
def getImageForBox(box, imgMain):
    val = list(box.xyxy)[0]
    x1 = int(val[0])
    y1 = int(val[1])
    x2 = int(val[2])
    y2 = int(val[3])
    return imgMain[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```